# How to compare Last.Write.Time using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I wanted to write script which will merge files to one, IF they were modified later then the one which should be a destination. My script looks like this:

```
Function UnifyConfigs { param ( $destination = "C:\temp\all.txt", [Parameter()] $files )

foreach ($config in $files) {
    If((Get-ChildItem $config ).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime)
    {
        Clear-Content -path $destination
        Set-Content -path $destination -value (Get-Content $config) 
    }
    else {
        break
    }  
}
}
```

My main problem is that $destination file is modified ALWAYS . As far as I understand it should be changed only if modification date of $config is greater than modification date of $destination. But now, it is overwritten each time I run script. What is wrong?

Comment: `($destination).LastWriteTime` -> `(Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime`

Comment: Mathias, I edited the code per your suggestion, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$destination` as defined in your `param` block is a *string* - you need to resolve the corresponding item in the file system provider to get to the `LastWriteTime` value - here using [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item):

```
if((Get-Item $config).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item $destination).LastWriteTime)
{
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however can you be more specific ? how should I do this? should I convert it to date  and then compare it ? or?

Comment: @Patrycja See the example code in my answer - `Get-Item` will return an `FileInfo` object with the `LastWriteTime` attribute

Comment: @Patrycja That's great :-D If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left :)